# Silverlight custom control ToolTip not showing up each time

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls, tooltip

In a Silverlight application I have a custom control with a number of custom properties. In the declaration class of the custom control additionally to defining its properties as dependency properties, I define showing a ToolTip:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Border bordercntr = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_SBorder") as Border;
        bordercntr.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(bordercntr_MouseEnter);
        bordercntr.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(bordercntr_MouseLeave);

    }

    private void bordercntr_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       string _sno = this.SomeProperty.ToString();

       ToolTipService.SetToolTip(this, "Some text " + _sno);
       VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Hovered",false);                            
    }
```

The problem is, that a ToolTip pops up not the first time mouse points to a custom control, but only after the second time. After I reload page this happens again: the first time I hover over a control nothing is shown up and then from the second time and further on the ToolTip pops up again. (not always in a stable way, I mean not 100% each time mouse hovers).

What could prevent the ToolTip from showing up in a stable manner each time a mouse hovers over control and starting showing up from the very first time of hovering it after reloading the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `ToolTip` in the setter for `SomeProperty`  The ToolTip you define in the `ToolTipService` will behave like a normal ToolTip and only appear when the mouse is over the control.  You shouldn't need to handle the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events at all.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I need to combine the text for the ToolTip out of several properties of the control? Where in this case should I put the ToolTip definition?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to have a private method that sets the ToolTip correctly and then call that method from each setter involved.  If any of the properties involved get changed just update your ToolTip.

Comment: Thanks, Stephan. I havn't yet tried your last proposal, but your remark on the fact that there is no reason to handle **MouseEnter** event have led me to what seems to work OK now - I put the **ToolTipService.SetToolTip** inside the **OnApplyTemplate()** and ToolTips are now working stable. +1